# Disabling asset fingerprinting with asset_path for a single asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I want to use the normal asset name, e.g. `app.js` when calling the `asset_path` helper in my views. In production, it uses the cache-busting name, e.g. `app-f73cf13e6f100eda6681381e7d3ae9eb.js`.

Is there a way to get the normal name using `asset_path`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figured it out, pretty simple actually. Just have to add `digest: false` to asset_path like so:

`asset_path('app.js', digest: false)`

Comment: Where do you put that ?

Comment: @AirWick219 what do you mean?

Comment: `code' background: url('select2.png'); <-- in my css file `code`. where do i put that so that this image it wouldn't be finger printed ?

Comment: @AirWick219 You can add `.erb` to your `.css` file's extension, then use the ruby helper, e.g. `background: url:('<%= asset_path('app.js', :digest => false) %>');`. This will run your css file through the ERB preprocessor first.

Comment: @Aditya Sanghi sadly you were right. Is there any way to disable digesting for a single file?

Answer (score 11):

By default assets.digest is enable in production environment and is recommended for several reasons. However, if you really want to disable it write this in your production.rb

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

For more info refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Hmmm, any way to do it just for a single asset path though? I don't want to disable the others.