# Rails production asset pipeline inserting random string into file name in the wrong place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I tried my hardest to search for this issue, but had no idea how to describe it let alone search for it, so I figured I would post what I have and if it's a duplicate someone will let me know. Been a long time SO reader, but never asked my own question before so this is exciting for me :)

So on a typical Rails production environment (Rails 3.2 + Ruby 1.9.3) the asset pipeline will add a random string of numbers and letters to asset file names, so application.css becomes something like application-2df8ae4bac143d750f200d4768826126.css

Well, a few images are having an issue in production where the file names are being incorrectly modified. This is only happening on the active buttons for some reason. For example, if I have button.jpg for initial and once clicked it becomes button-2df8ae4bac143d750f-hover.jpg when the original is button-hover.jpg so I'm guessing maybe something to do with precompiling? Any help would be GREATLY appreciated and also sorry in advance if this is a duplicate post.

Comment: It might help to know that they are jquery tabs

Comment: what happens if you rename the file button_hover.jpg and recompile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's two solutions via [Disabling asset fingerprinting with asset_path for a single asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960074/disabling-asset-fingerprinting-with-asset-path-for-a-single-asset)

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.digest = false
```

or

```
# single asset
asset_path('app.js', :digest => false)
```

It's called "fingerprinting", see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark